# Sign ws-security header containing token from Active STS

Tags: wcf, wif, ws-security

This seems like it should be handled natively so I am likely doing something wrong.  I have a WCF client which calls an Active STS and uses the token from the RTSR to generate the WS-Security header included in the call to the RP.  The RP requires that the header be signed, which seems a fair enough request.  However, the WS-Security header generated by the client does not include a signature and I cannot see how to configured it to do so.  The generated header is below.  As can be seen it contains a signature for the assertion and the subjectconfirmationdata both of which are responsibilities of the STS.  The "missing" header signature, in my limited understanding, is a responsibility of the client.  So is what configuration/code that needs to be added in order to get a signature block that is a child element of the Security header much like the reference header below.

**Client Generated WS-Security header**

```
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2015-08-24T21:04:41.090Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2015-08-24T21:09:41.090Z</u:Expires>
    </u:Timestamp>
    <Assertion ID="_fea24920-d64c-4758-b51e-61208cb5084f" IssueInstant="2015-08-24T21:04:40.060Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:WindowsDomainQualifiedName">MySTS</Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#_fea24920-d64c-4758-b51e-61208cb5084f">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>/tfOnmKqjmkK8gH1GMNQ/XJ5gdtwzvcJTqxwiZJ7noQ=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>dGz1dN9odSSpblmgczWWRG6tF66oonOHAVJCSC5uqjCOH+18cjJfX/duqb0sv1w0VxGsKIzR0VZ74V5Pq5MWsKQArIgEwO/wnUEOcKPI9J3KlL/IU7XLJNFtVO/ioKB4ps34S/5vZLB+WxXryz5ylBd5JvVFT7cf9R68kSxY9IurxELCGdhe/YIgJtgI6JsEoqqk7314sUZj8qrCy5zUbEVufyyStCI23OIunXPQceksa/csdaTmHFPNkYtHY8yUmyzT8aKBVKZVG2iluXySoi0TwTiVH+4ImGqXKV+VhUebCwqQwAur1IWAu+V/r7ZkW7C0384ATkMTmmLXRhom3g==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <KeyValue>
                    <RSAKeyValue>
                        <Modulus>2kUArhFnRE+a0oof35YUv0Pc8w+UHox/PlTxzDnp86eyiLggHj76egrVbtV6TpYXw783JUQb+NiKxm0V/f6DIeqFWvCeHfzFJaWntNwAjOULY3z0n4T5gJuHpk3/JtefBXBm2m5zW4OhvijMfU228oQ5kJDpuEmkcSgmyZwyPwbJZlLAS3agrFvMu+r7qU4O6imaCAoTt/QYHIo2TLKpprXSOFrszwJDz3I5XTGaE+peBlQueFg5XvlAlARqDfq3yCcP5Mlel1Xv6kFIv/0LBMCZ1U8zMgVQsKOGgnSXCGgyq+77nvS+MPSBc71jkSWh4FnxDFTlL1j1iGdH1BIkWQ==</Modulus>
                        <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
                    </RSAKeyValue>
                </KeyValue>
            </KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <Subject>
            <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">JoeTester@example.org</NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:holder-of-key">
                <SubjectConfirmationData a:type="KeyInfoConfirmationDataType" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <KeyValue>
                            <RSAKeyValue>
                                <Modulus>2kUArhFnRE+a0oof35YUv0Pc8w+UHox/PlTxzDnp86eyiLggHj76egrVbtV6TpYXw783JUQb+NiKxm0V/f6DIeqFWvCeHfzFJaWntNwAjOULY3z0n4T5gJuHpk3/JtefBXBm2m5zW4OhvijMfU228oQ5kJDpuEmkcSgmyZwyPwbJZlLAS3agrFvMu+r7qU4O6imaCAoTt/QYHIo2TLKpprXSOFrszwJDz3I5XTGaE+peBlQueFg5XvlAlARqDfq3yCcP5Mlel1Xv6kFIv/0LBMCZ1U8zMgVQsKOGgnSXCGgyq+77nvS+MPSBc71jkSWh4FnxDFTlL1j1iGdH1BIkWQ==</Modulus>
                                <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
                            </RSAKeyValue>
                        </KeyValue>
                    </KeyInfo>
                </SubjectConfirmationData>
            </SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2015-08-24T20:59:36.114Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-08-24T22:09:36.114Z"/>
        <AttributeStatement>
            <!-- attributes where here -->
        </AttributeStatement>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-08-24T21:04:36.130Z">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</o:Security>
```

**The client side WCF Binding**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <ws2007HttpBinding>
                <binding>
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </ws2007HttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding>
                    <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport" requireSignatureConfirmation="true" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10" messageProtectionOrder="EncryptBeforeSign"
                    keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" includeTimestamp="true">
                        <issuedTokenParameters keyType="BearerKey" tokenType="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
                            <issuer address="" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"/>
                        </issuedTokenParameters>
                        <localClientSettings></localClientSettings>
                        <secureConversationBootstrap />
                    </security>
                    <mtomMessageEncoding maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                    <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" maxBufferPoolSize="134217728" maxReceivedMessageSize="134217728" maxBufferSize="134217728" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint binding="customBinding" contract="IReplacable" name="*" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Reference Security Header**

```
 <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="timestamp1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Created>2015-08-21T22:34:49.138Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2016-08-21T22:34:49.138Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
    <saml2:Assertion ID="a956b920-4956-47c6-8a05-8a3a56e418a0" IssueInstant="2015-08-21T22:29:49.138Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName">CN=SAMLUser,OU=SU,O=SAML User,L=LosAngeles,ST=CA,C=US</saml2:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#a956b920-4956-47c6-8a05-8a3a56e418a0">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>guh8xR0Vu+3X3LlLAu7SJ0wCKXw=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>2X2UmgJMLGQIzN73pxxyQZVVttnE8xAkPmScvFCX2zlrS7QdmqM+BoJswtmDImK9wAhXC0WtY17U C97Iw7brHrmNtQa3tM+4JClSCuW6SM6OjHn3qMLHiUJrpIZ1k0YAYfLcIF9S7x5lYFKUzWk+oOz1 3LMOMsjORXCssUpzd3BCOUhSSeg9+6b76ZyqTeaFqldn1OmG9jz3QS+h/vUo24h1ohKPJqEcE9sG 3Ab3LqyYv8ASVP9DsKRjOjxGKfhFT5WD9gW10IqQY2YGyYtguHfsyf05dPGBuXB8jaPZ3wgYsYXU FMmjRmuAYQkdQQRH8ju4HwtWdGnTtCQBRoqboA==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:KeyValue>
                    <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                        <ds:Modulus>2kUArhFnRE+a0oof35YUv0Pc8w+UHox/PlTxzDnp86eyiLggHj76egrVbtV6TpYXw783JUQb+NiK xm0V/f6DIeqFWvCeHfzFJaWntNwAjOULY3z0n4T5gJuHpk3/JtefBXBm2m5zW4OhvijMfU228oQ5 kJDpuEmkcSgmyZwyPwbJZlLAS3agrFvMu+r7qU4O6imaCAoTt/QYHIo2TLKpprXSOFrszwJDz3I5 XTGaE+peBlQueFg5XvlAlARqDfq3yCcP5Mlel1Xv6kFIv/0LBMCZ1U8zMgVQsKOGgnSXCGgyq+77 nvS+MPSBc71jkSWh4FnxDFTlL1j1iGdH1BIkWQ==</ds:Modulus>
                        <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
                    </ds:RSAKeyValue>
                </ds:KeyValue>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName">CN=SAMLUser,OU=SU,O=SAML User,L=LosAngeles,ST=CA,C=US</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:holder-of-key">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData>
                    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:KeyValue>
                            <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                                <ds:Modulus>2kUArhFnRE+a0oof35YUv0Pc8w+UHox/PlTxzDnp86eyiLggHj76egrVbtV6TpYXw783JUQb+NiK xm0V/f6DIeqFWvCeHfzFJaWntNwAjOULY3z0n4T5gJuHpk3/JtefBXBm2m5zW4OhvijMfU228oQ5 kJDpuEmkcSgmyZwyPwbJZlLAS3agrFvMu+r7qU4O6imaCAoTt/QYHIo2TLKpprXSOFrszwJDz3I5 XTGaE+peBlQueFg5XvlAlARqDfq3yCcP5Mlel1Xv6kFIv/0LBMCZ1U8zMgVQsKOGgnSXCGgyq+77 nvS+MPSBc71jkSWh4FnxDFTlL1j1iGdH1BIkWQ==</ds:Modulus>
                                <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
                            </ds:RSAKeyValue>
                        </ds:KeyValue>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                </saml2:SubjectConfirmationData>
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-08-21T22:27:49.138Z" SessionIndex="123456">
            <saml2:SubjectLocality/>
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:X509 </saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
        <saml2:AttributeStatement>
            <!-- attributes-->
        </saml2:AttributeStatement>
        <saml2:AuthzDecisionStatement Decision="Permit" Resource="">
            <saml2:Action Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:action:rwedc">Execute</saml2:Action>
            <saml2:Evidence>
                <saml2:Assertion ID="_3e0d08ce-a126-45e8-b602-ac0c7ea075ce" IssueInstant="2015-08-21T22:29:49.138Z" Version="2.0">
                    <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName">CN=SAML User,OU=SU,O=SAML User,L=Los Angeles,ST=CA,C=US</saml2:Issuer>
                    <saml2:Subject>
                        <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName">CN=SAMLUser,OU=SU,O=SAML User,L=LosAngeles,ST=CA,C=US</saml2:NameID>
                    </saml2:Subject>
                    <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2015-08-21T21:34:49.138Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-08-21T23:34:49.138Z"/>
                    <saml2:AttributeStatement>
                        <saml2:Attribute Name="AccessConsentPolicy" NameFormat="http://www.hhs.gov/healthit/nhin">
                            <saml2:AttributeValue>urn:oid:1.2.3.4</saml2:AttributeValue>
                        </saml2:Attribute>
                        <saml2:Attribute Name="InstanceAccessConsentPolicy" NameFormat="http://www.hhs.gov/healthit/nhin">
                            <saml2:AttributeValue>urn:oid:1.2.3.4.123456789 </saml2:AttributeValue>
                        </saml2:Attribute>
                    </saml2:AttributeStatement>
                </saml2:Assertion>
            </saml2:Evidence>
        </saml2:AuthzDecisionStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#timestamp1">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>qs//Jxv/CVrDvTxn8hYvdSe1pbY=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>uf13RmBH95fP4o6x6eXC84+gkoLeZqLshw0ycm8t6HJP0+OtVEPZJbAw/UF2i2rzDk6oFE/Rxe1l /cks9HkIyNBEIwt2VY1hUldWfGd1cDq6Pi/H3EGuMasr42Qm8ObPCkSFqXhgowtIsSR9amo3e1KO YBsjYLnidcaZi7B1c6DjH1GozgSgdZDrYANUJr/KJ8zDDhGU09WXEuOekx41YvS4nWn/EHJbV+xf zKTN9ds+91PtFL1nnjqJT9BH4V2TvnRildsh7BeoMqQrXuePp7FxxgxCtg5tB15gDrNS1mOLorQZ 5UwqSrLp2/WkGkpzabMf2oN56lkiB6IHvsZ+Yg==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLID">a956b920-4956-47c6-8a05-8a3a56e418a0</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
</wsse:Security>
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers are not signed since you are using bearer key token, as set in your configuration

```
<issuedTokenParameters keyType="BearerKey"...>
```

It needs to be either a symmetric key or asymmetrickey. Looking at your reference SOAP header, you'll need an asymmetrickey token.

The simplest way is to use ws2007FederationBinding. If you have to use a custom binding (as in your config), here is a sample config from MSDN at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa734714(v=vs.100).aspx

```
<issuedTokenParameters 
      DefaultMessageSecurityVersion="System.ServiceModel.MessageSecurityVersion"
      inclusionMode="AlwaysToInitiator/AlwaysToRecipient/Never/Once"
      keySize="Integer"
   keyType="AsymmetricKey/BearerKey/SymmetricKey"
      tokenType="String" >
    <additionalRequestParameters />
    <claimTypeRequirements>
        <add claimType="URI"
           isOptional="Boolean" />
    </claimTypeRequirements>
    <issuer address="String" 
                      binding=" " />
    <issuerMetadata address="String" /> 
</issuedTokenParameters>
```

You can omit the issuer element and obtain the SAML token separately from your STS using WS-Trust, and use the token to secure your outgoing message to RP.